# Counting the length of JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I recently asked this question on SO: [Grabbing JSON works from one link, not from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982851/grabbing-json-works-from-one-link-not-from-another)

I got an answer basically saying that `getContentLength` is optional by the server, so I would have to manually count the length myself. Well, it took me some time but I came up with some code that seems to get the right count, but I'm not sure if it's the "right" way to do it. Mostly because of my `while(0==0)` statement.

The exact answer I got was:

> content-length is a header set by the responding server. It is
>   optional, and google chooses not to send it for dynamically generated
>   content (most servers don't). So you'll have to read the stream until
>   you're out of bytes, rather than doing it in one go.

So this is my code that I came up with:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
int contentLength=0;
int cur;
while (0==0){
cur = reader.read();
if (cur == -1) {
break;
} else {
contentLength++;
}
}
```

Does that seem like a viable solution for counting the content length when the server doesn't provide you with one?

Comment: Better replace while(0==0) with while(true) but why do you need the size at all. You can't really get the size without reading all the data.

Comment: If you read my other question, I'm simply just trying to get the JSON data, but the way I'm doing it now requires a length of content. Do you see a better way?

Comment: If you are using an existing JSon parser library, then that library most likely got a method which can parse Json directly from a stream. But if you try to write your own json parse(Why???) then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can easily count the byte length of `InputStream` content sent by server in 2 lines:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputStream);
int length = bias.toByteArray().length;
```

Related to your approach:

```
int contentLength=0;
while (reader.read()>0){
contentLength++;
}
```

But what happens with the answer proposed in the question refered:
`int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();`

That one is perfectly reasonable and viable.

Comment: Don't use this on large streams though-  toByteArray creates a copy of the data in an array.  That's expensive in terms of time and memory.

Comment: Large... as in? 800 characters? or 8,000?

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, agree. But if its matter of small responses, time and allocated memory can be negligible.

Comment: @EGHDK Large in quantity in bytes.